# C++ Overloaded function and errors

Tags: c++, vector, overloading

In my `main` class I've got a vector of pointer (`vector<Corsa*> listaCorse`) 
I want insert my `Corsa*` object inside my ordered vector 
So I create an iterator, and I pass him `listaCorse.begin(), listaCorse.end(), myPointerToTheObject, &sortFunction)`

**Resolved**: I don't know why, but I just included algorithm and vector, and now it compiles. 
I really don't know why, because I included them inside the myhugeclass.h file, but it works, and that's ok
Thank you everyone :)

**Problem**: sortFunction is a static function inside my 'Corsa' class. And it is overloaded.
The two prototypers are:

```
bool Corsa::cmpCorse(Corsa *a, Corsa *b)
bool Corsa::cmpCorse(Corsa &a, Corsa &b)
```

Obviously I want to pass to him the first one, because mine is a vector of pointer
But my compiler doesn't like my code so much, so it says me 'unresolved overload function type'

Can anyone help me? :)
Thank you so much
This is the snippet of code:

```
// corsa.h
class Corsa{
    ...
    static int cmpCorsa(const Corsa& a, const Corsa& b);
    static int cmpCorsa(const Corsa *a, const Corsa *b);
    ...
}

// myhugeclass.cpp
int MyHugeClass::addCorsa(Corsa *a){
    vector<Corsa*>::iterator low = lower_bound(listaCorse.begin(), listaCorse.end(), c, &Corsa::cmpCorsa);
    listaCorse.insert(low, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you :)

EDIT: I made a big mistake, but not related tthis error. I passed the wrong function, I should pass `static bool Corsa::sortCorsa(Corsa *a, Corsa *b)`
Also this function is overloaded
As chris said (thank you chris), I try to do this:

```
int MyHugeClass::addCorsa(Corsa *c){

    typedef bool(*Func)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*);
    vector<Corsa*>::iterator low = lower_bound(listaCorse.begin(), listaCorse.end(), c, static_cast<Func>(&Corsa::sortCorsa));
    listaCorse.insert(low, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the error changes in `[Error] no matching function for call to 'lower_bound(std::vector<Corsa*>::iterator, std::vector<Corsa*>::iterator, Corsa*&, bool (*)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*))'`

Comment: The compiler doesn't know which `cmpCorsa` address should it take.

Comment: comparison functions return bool, not int.  That isn't the reason for your error, but you should at least make the function fit what std::sort expects.

Comment: You wrote `bool` in the first snippet and `int` in the second snippet.

Comment: I've got also the sort functions: static bool sortCorsa(const Corsa *a, const Corsa *b); but also this function is overloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example that compiles cleanly that uses std::sort.  Note the typedef and the cast

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
struct Corsa
{
    static bool cmpCorsa(const Corsa& a, const Corsa& b);
    static bool cmpCorsa(const Corsa *a, const Corsa *b);
};

typedef bool (*fn)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*);
int main()
{
   std::vector<Corsa*> C;
   std::sort(C.begin(), C.end(), static_cast<fn>(&Corsa::cmpCorsa));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can cast it to the right type:

```
typedef bool(*Func)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*);
vector<Corsa*>::iterator low = lower_bound(..., static_cast<Func>(&Corsa::sortCorsa));
```

Comment: [Error] invalid static_cast from type '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to type 'Func {aka bool (*)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*)}' :(

Comment: @Ignus If `cmpCorsa` returns `bool` then change the return type of the function pointer typedef accordingly: `typedef bool(*Func)(const Corsa*, const Corsa*);`

Comment: @Ignus, I was going from the larger code snippet. I'll change it then, but due to inconsistencies, I have no idea whether those parameters are `const` or not.

Comment: Oh, It's not a problem :) thank you so much for your help :) I just tested it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer, and then maybe not...

When using *sorted* vectors (or deques) I have often found that using `std::lower_bound` was not as practical as using `std::partial_sort`:

```
// assume vec is sorted
size_t const currentSize = vec.size();

vec.push_back(...); // like usual
// or
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(vec));

std::partial_sort(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + currentSize, vec.end() /*, comparator*/);
```

It's as efficient as `std::lower_bound` on a single insertion, and has the potential to be more efficient when multiple insertions take place.

Note: a call to `std::sort` also works, and the implementation is usually optimized to take advantage of sorted runs, but it still seems wasteful.